# Weird redirection issue on nginx server while directing to index.html

Tags: nginx, file-permissions, user-permissions, 500-error

I am trying to deploy a single page application using nginx and here is the configuration below.

```
 server {
    listen 24670 default_server;
    listen [::]:24670 default_server;
    server_name *******;

        root /home/gerry/client/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
           try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the page, I would get a 500 Internal Server Error and on checking the logs, I would see the following error.

```
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [crit] 8752#8752: *2 stat() "/home/gerry/client/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
2017/10/15 18:20:17 [error] 8752#8752: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 183.83.241.76, server: app.url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.url.com:24670"
```

I have already set the permissions and ownership to www-data and am not sure what else I need to do to serve the index.html file

Comment: Did you check the permission at every directory level and not only on the index.html I.e. with `namei -m /home/gerry/client/dist/index.html`  ?  SELinux?

Comment: I wonder if the redirect cycle is caused by the "/index.html" in the try_files statement. Given the index statement I wonder if you can change that to " try_files $uri /;" Not sure if this will work but worth a shot.

Comment: It was indeed the folder and file permissions. For now I have moved it to the /var/www folder.

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is a permission problem, check that the user running the server can reach index.html (the entire path).

The redirection is caused by the try_files directive, add a 404 as a catchall last try to stop it even in case of errors.